# Options Menu not Inflating from xml

Tags: android, menubar, android-inflate

I am having trouble inflating an options menu from xml. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It runs fine when I press the menu button on the emulator but there is no menu bar when I run it on an actual device running ics.

Answer (score 0):

The menu-button was removed from devices which run Android 3.0 and higher and is now considered "deprecated". There is [a nice Blog-post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) about why, how to use the new ActionBar and how to keep legacy support for older applications:

> If your app runs on a device without a dedicated Menu button, the
>   system decides whether to add the action overflow to the navigation
>   bar based on which API levels you declare to support in the `<uses-sdk>`
>   manifest element. The logic boils down to:
>
> - If you set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher, the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
> - Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running on Android 3.0 or higher.
> - The only exception is that if you set `minSdkVersion` to 10 or lower, set `targetSdkVersion` to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar,
>     the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app
>     on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

If you're starting Android development or you're creating a new application now, don't use this kind of menu but rather use the ActionBar.

Helpers are available in the ["Support Library"](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using) for backwards-compatibility:

> The ActionBar is **not supported** by the library. However, when creating
>   your Options Menu, you can *declare which items should be added to the
>   Action Bar* when it's available (on Android 3.0 or later).